# ngnix issue with chrome redirection non-www to www

Tags: linux, nginx

I have done basic configuration for my site to run using nginx,

```
server {
        listen 80;
        

        root /home/htdocs/;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;


access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args /;
    }
    # added error page
    error_page 404 = @notfound;

    location @notfound {
       return 301 /;
    }
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include  fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
 location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

}


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl;
# SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0002/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0002/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0002/chain.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
root /home/htdocs/;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

server_name www.example.com;
#return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;


location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args /;
    }
    # added error page
    error_page 404 = @notfound;
    location @notfound {
       return 301 /;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include  fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }

 location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }

}
```

> Whats wrong with above config even I tried in incognito mode of google-chrome but still same.

Hope to hear from you with solution if I'm doing any thing wrong.

Regards

I have tried different solutions and parameters noting work out for me.